# Excel transpose column with macros data loop

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have a problem , I have a column with some data.

I want to transpose all of this data automatically with a macro.

I have  cells in the column with some special text this is the end of the first row end the 2 row and 3.. how can i do this ? the cells range"s are random.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code will copy loop through all the non-blank cells in column 1 of the ActiveSheet and transpose them to the adjacent cells starting at B1. You need to change `"Condition Text"` to a statement that matches when the end of each row is round. Because you haven't specified what makes the last cell unique to the rest, you'll need to write this part yourself.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub TransposeCol()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    Dim n As Long
    n = 2

    While sht.Cells(i, 1) <> "Condition Text"
        sht.Cells(1, n) = sht.Cells(i, 1)
        i = i + 1
        n = n + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it"s works fine but not copy in to the 2nd row after the loop.

Comment: @AntiRácz made some changes to the code. Let me know how it works for you.